# Refresh Value NodeJS (DiscordJS) GameDig

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, gamedig

I'm making a Discord bot that allows to give indications of a game server. I use the GameDig library, but the values don't refresh. I have to restart the app (`bot.js`) to see the changes. I'd like it to refresh every `x` time automatically...

I tried with `setInterval(() => { ... }, 6000);`.

```js
const Gamedig = require('gamedig');
Gamedig.query({
    type: 'garrysmod',
    host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
    port: '27015'
}).then((state) => {
    console.log(state);
    let nom = state.name
    let carte = state.map
    let joueursmax = state.maxplayers
    let joueurs = state.players.length
    let latence = state.ping

    client.on('ready', () => {
        client.user.setStatus('online')
        setInterval(() => {
            client.user.setActivity(joueurs+'/'+joueursmax+' Joueurs');
        }, 6000);
```

Also, I can't use variables from the game `state` in my message handler (`nom`, `carte`, etc.):

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


  // Commandes State
  if (command === 'state') {  
    message.channel.send('__**Nom**__: '+nom);
    message.channel.send('__**Map**__: '+carte);
    message.channel.send('__**Joueurs**__: '+joueurs+'/'+joueursmax);
    message.channel.send('__**Latence**__: '+latence+' ms');
  }

  // other commands...
  if (command === 'say') {
  message.delete().catch()
      message.channel.send(args.join(" ")).catch(console.error);

  }
  if (command === 'ping') {  
    message.channel.send(` BotServer01: Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare `state` on the top so you can access it in both `client.on('message')` and `client.on('ready')`. You can update this `state` variable from your interval every time you receive a response from your game server.

You can set up this interval when the bot is ready, but make sure that you fetch the state every `x` seconds if you want to update it. In your current code, when you fetch outside the `setInterval`, it only fetches once, and uses the same state every time. So, you need to move it into the `setInterval`'s callback.

I've used the [destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get and rename state variables. I've also used async/await to handle promises, maybe it's a bit easier to read:

```js
// declare state outside of client.on, so you can access it in both "ready"
// and "message"
let state = null;

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'state') {
    // if state is null just send an error message
    if (!state) {
      return message.channel.send('Oops, game state is not yet available');
    }

    // destructure state
    const {
      name: nom,
      map: carte,
      maxplayers: joueursmax,
      ping: latence,
      players: { length: joueurs },
    } = state;

    message.channel.send('__**Nom**__: ' + nom);
    message.channel.send('__**Map**__: ' + carte);
    message.channel.send('__**Joueurs**__: ' + joueurs + '/' + joueursmax);
    message.channel.send('__**Latence**__: ' + latence + ' ms');
  }

  // other commands...
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  client.user.setStatus('online');

  setInterval(async () => {
    try {
      // update the state declared outside these functions
      // no const, let, var keywords needed
      state = await Gamedig.query({
        type: 'garrysmod',
        host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
        port: '27015',
      });

      const {
        maxplayers: joueursmax,
        players: { length: joueurs },
      } = state;

      client.user.setActivity(`${joueurs}/${joueursmax} Joueurs`);
    } catch (e) {
      // you need to handle the error somehow!
      console.log(e);
    }
  }, 6000);
});
```

If you don't want to use async/await and destructuring, this one should work:

```js
let state = null;

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'state') {
    // if state is null, just send an error message
    if (!state) {
      return message.channel.send('Oops, game state is not yet available');
    }

    const nom = state.name;
    const carte = state.map;
    const joueursmax = state.maxplayers;
    const joueurs = state.players.length;
    const latence = state.ping;

    message.channel.send('__**Nom**__: ' + nom);
    message.channel.send('__**Map**__: ' + carte);
    message.channel.send('__**Joueurs**__: ' + joueurs + '/' + joueursmax);
    message.channel.send('__**Latence**__: ' + latence + ' ms');
  }

  // other commands...
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  client.user.setStatus('online');

  setInterval(() => {
    Gamedig.query({
      type: 'garrysmod',
      host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
      port: '27015',
    })
      .then((updatedState) => {
        state = updatedState;

        const joueursmax = state.maxplayers;
        const joueurs = state.players.length;

        client.user.setActivity(`${joueurs}/${joueursmax} Joueurs`);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }, 6000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are querying your game server only once. If you want to refresh your value and send it to discord, then you have to change the order.

- first you get the discord client
- then you query your game server
- finally you get the refreshed value

```
// connected to your discord client
client.on('ready', () => {
  client.user.setStatus('online')
  
  // you want to refresh your data every 6 seconds
  setInterval(() => {
    // query your game server
    Gamedig.query({
      type: 'garrysmod',
      host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
      port: '27015'
    }).then((state) => {
      const joueursmax = state.maxplayers
      const joueurs = state.players.length
      
      // send new data to your discord server
      client.user.setActivity(joueurs+'/'+joueursmax+' Joueurs');
    });
  }, 6000); 
});
```

On a side note, you should use `const` over `let` [when you can](https://overreacted.io/on-let-vs-const/).

Comment: Little tip. Check that you don't reach the rate limit from discord with `setActivity`. I would change the activity every 20 seconds or 25, because this won't get yourself rate limited